# Is it possible to increase the strength of the LTE signal by manually setting the Earfcn Number in the modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, modem

I have a green packet gp-2101 modem, and its LTE signal strength has been weak for a few days, I want to know if it is possible to increase the signal strength by manually setting the Earfcn Number in the modem?
If possible, how can I find and set the best Earfcn Number?

Comment: Doubtful as that channel is determined by your service provider

Comment: Also the channels depend from the settings of cell. So changing on modem the channel probably will not work. Try to move the modem around the house to see where you get better signal.

Comment: Moving does not affect it and it used to have a good speed in this place